# c++ STL compile undefined reference

Tags: c++, c++11

read.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
std::vector<std::string> col_repeat(std::string pattern, std::string item);
```

read.cpp

```
#include "read.h"




std::vector<std::string> col_repeat(std::string pattern, std::string item)
{

    std::regex str_expr_2(pattern);
    std::smatch  sm_2;
    std::vector<std::string> collect;
    for (std::sregex_iterator it = std::sregex_iterator(item.begin(), item.end(), str_expr_2);
        it != std::sregex_iterator(); it++)
    {
        std::smatch match;
        match = *it;
        std::string temp(match[1].str());
        collect.push_back(temp);
    }
    return collect;
}
```

main_func_run.cpp define the main function

```
#include "read.h"

int main()
{

    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("chem.out");
    std::string item;
    std::getline(inFile,item);
    col_repeat("[0-0]+",item);

    inFile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Makefile

```
OPT= -std=c++11 -O2 -lstdc++


CPP= g++
EXE = target
objects=read.o main_func_run.o
 


default : $(objects) 
    $(CPP) $(OPT) $(objects) -o $(EXE)
    @echo " ------------------------------------------------------ " 
    @echo "         target has been successfully built." 
    @echo " ------------------------------------------------------ " 

clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) *.o


main_func_run.o : main_func_run.cpp read.o
    $(CPP) $(OPT)   -c main_func_run.cpp
read.o : read.cpp
    $(CPP) $(OPT)  -c read.cpp
```

I have defined c++ structs and functions to read in information from some quantum chemistry software. The .h file looks like above the .cpp file omitted. The code can be compiled successfully using visual studio. However, when I try to compile the same code on Linux using intel icpc compiler, there are errors like " undefined reference to std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits >::regex_iterator(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>" Looks that the main program using the functions defined here can not link to the corresponding functions in the .o file. Is it because in Linux the STL of C++ is not well supported by my compiler? should some special flags be added from the beginning?

For further explanation, I have made a minimal reproducible example of the original problem. Use the above Makefile and source code, g++ gives the following errors:

read.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits<char> >::regex_iterator(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::basic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> > const&, std::bitset<11ul>)' read.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to` std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits >::regex_iterator()'
read.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits<char> >::operator!=(std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits<char> > const&)' read.cpp:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to` std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits >::operator*()'
read.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits >::operator++(int)'

Comment: At a guess, you tried to link using `gcc` or `ld` instead of `g++`.  Both `gcc` and `g++` are capable of launching the linker (and will do so if `-c` option is not passed), but only the latter defaults to including the C++ standard library as linker input (with gcc or ld you can still explicitly specify it, with an option such as `-lstdc++` )

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt Thanks for your feed back ! I tried the -lstdc++ option, but still not works. Looks that I should first check how my linux system is configurated.

Comment: How are you building your software?  Makefile?  Project system in some integrated development environment?

Comment: Thanks for your message @BenVoigt. On linux, I use Makefile. The linux computer is a shared assets and It provides only basic installations for compilers. That is the reason  I first debug  code using VS and then compile it on linux using Makefile. Sometimes I also using CMake. But this time CMake don't work too much either.

Comment: Run `make` with a VERBOSE flag so you can see the exact command-line for the step that fails.  Take a look at that command-line to see if there's anything you didn't expect, and if you can't see the problem, add that command-line to your question.

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt Thanks for your suggestion. !I have made a minimal reproducible example of my original problem. Looks like the same problem persist.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the program builds without an error. What is your version of gcc? Do you have gcc installed in a way other than your package manager? Incidentally `-lstdc++` is not needed here.

Comment: Hi @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem thanks for your feedback ! My g++ version is 4.8.1

Comment: Hi @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  I changed to g++ 7.5 and now it worked. Thanks !

Comment: 4.8.1 is indeed too old to support std::regex.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your feed back again ~